# Dumpdata with unmanaged models

Tags: django, sqlite, dumpdata

I'm trying to dump my database (sqlite3) to a json file for a fixture, but I have an unmanaged model which is causing a `no such table` error (obviously!) so how do you dumpdata with these kind of models in the db?

Model:

```
from django.db import models


class Backup(models.Model):
    """
    This class is lazily recycled between various forms that ask the user to
    provide a path to some data.
    """

    dbloc = models.CharField(
        max_length = 255
    )

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'myApp'
        db_table = 'backup'
        managed = False
```

Error:

`CommandError: Unable to serialize database: no such table: backup`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just exclude this model using `--exclude` option. Quote from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dumpdata):

> The --exclude option may be provided to prevent specific applications
>   or models (specified as in the form of appname.ModelName) from being
>   dumped. If you specify a model name to dumpdata, the dumped output
>   will be restricted to that model, rather than the entire application.
>   You can also mix application names and model names.

```
./manage.py dumpdata myApp --exclude=myApp.Backup
```

Comment: Do you know why django does not automatically exclude unmanaged models from `dumpdata`?